# Jupyter notebook in vscode installing everytime I open VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I open VS Code & go to Extensions, it always shows Jupyter as Installing, Why is it so?

Comment: Do you have the python extension installed?

Comment: Yes, python extension is also installed in my computer

Comment: jupyter notebook is a dependency to python extension. That is why it is getting installed.